# Matrix - Fatal error: Class 'EE_Fieldtype' not found

Tags: matrix

really strange one, this.

I have a simple channel with one matrix field, which contains a single fieldtype of 'date'. It works in the control panel OK, but if I try to run the tag pair on the front end I get:

Fatal error: Class 'EE_Fieldtype' not found in /path/to/_system/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php on line 14

This is EE v2.6.1 - Build Date: 20130506, and Matrix 2.5.5 or 2.5.6. But I have both Matrix and EE working OK on other projects at these versions so I'm stumped.

Anyone have any suggestions better than my "start again" one?

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: Andy, are you running any other add-ons by any chance?

Comment: Hi Lisa. I'm running these (sorry about formatting):

DataGrab 1.7.7  [ MOD ] 
Assets 2.1.4  [ MOD FLD ] 
Developer 1.7.1  [ ACC ] 
devot:ee Monitor 1.2.4  [ ACC ] 
Field Editor 1.0.4  [ MOD ] 
HTTP Header 1.0.5  [ PLG ] 
IfElse 1.4  [ PLG ] 
Matrix 2.5.6  [ EXT FLD ] 
Mountee 2.3  [ MOD ] 
NavEE 2.2.7  [ MOD EXT FLD ] 
NSM Better Meta 1.1.5.1  [ MOD ] 
NSM Morphine theme 2.0.3  [ ACC ] 
Playa 4.4.5  [ MOD EXT FLD ] 
Stash 2.3.9  [ MOD EXT ] 
Structure 3.3.10  [ MOD EXT ] 
Switchee 2.0.6  [ PLG ] 
Wygwam 3.1.1  [ MOD FLD ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem - I had custom fields disabled in my entries tag (d'oh!)!!

This seems to cause the aforementioned problem if you try to parse matrix tags.

Comment: Hey Andy, Can you please mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Hi Brandon - I can't until tomorrow, but I will!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the date issue with Matrix 2.5.5. Try upgrading to 2.5.6.

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/changelog.html

> Fixed the Date celltype for EE 2.6.
>
> Fixed a bug where an illegal date string could crash EE.

There was also a problem with the installer.

Comment: This is the strange thing, it does sound exactly like that bug but I'm getting it on 2.5.6 aswell!